# What does '[' (left square bracket) do when treated as a function?

Tags: r

I tried a simple test, but I am not sure how to interpret the results correctly.

```
a <- 1:10
b <- lapply(a,'[',2)
```

The code I am analyzing used the `lapply` function along with the arguments listed above.

The output confused me as it gave me a list of 10 int values, all of which were `NA`. This probably means `a` needs to be a list, but I am not sure.

I couldn't find anything with a google search, and I am not sure how to interpret my test (if I even used it in the correct context).

Comment: That'd be similar to `b = lapply(a, function(x) x[2])`

Comment: ...which is why it returns all NAs; it treats each element of `a` as a length one vector and tries to extract the 2nd element, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Look at `help(Extract)`.

Comment: Try, `my_list = list(1:5, 2:6, 3:7)` as your input.